# Django template forloop and if condition problem

Tags: html, django

if looped reach 7, it will add or change td just like the second picture showed

```
{% for match in matches %}
   <tr>
      <td class="tblcore">{{match.id}}. {{match.Marking__Marking}}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

this is i want result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a `tr` every forth column:

```
<tr>
{% for match in matches %}
    <td class="tblcore">{{match.id}}. {{match.Marking__Marking}}</td>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```